# WinAppDriver: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session

Tags: java, selenium, appium, winappdriver

I am trying to automate tests in a desktop application developed in Delphi, using WinAppDriver.

- Programming language: Java 1.8.0_281
- IDE: Eclipse, Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
- selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
- Appium: java-client-7.4.1.jar
- commons-lang3-3.12.0

  public class Demo {

  ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       WindowsDriver driver = null;

       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
       capabilities.setCapability("app", "<path_of_exe_file>");
       capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Windows");
       capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
       try {
           driver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
   }
  ```

  }

The application starts with an info-splash screen and then main application is launched. However following error is displayed in the console:

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: Failed to locate opened application window with appId: <path_of_exe_file>, and processId: 1936 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)**

Please let me know, how to solve this.

Comment: Is WinAppDriver.exe running?

Comment: What is your real `"<path_of_exe_file>"` in `capabilities.setCapability("app", "<path_of_exe_file>");`? If not secret.

Comment: Yes, WinAppDriver.exe is running.

Comment: capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\abc def\\ghi.jk\\somefolder\\someapplication.exe");

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the WinAppDriver. And the app id should be the path of the desktop application you want to automate.

Comment: I had the WinAppDriver installed and was running.

I had used the "app" value correctly.

FYI, notepad.exe works correctly for me.

Comment: Are you manually able to invoke the app by clicking on the exe file. Also did you check in taskmanager if winapp driver had invoked the app and the process is running in task manager for that app. sometimes kill all the process related to app or restart the system help

Comment: Not only manually, the application is started automatically also. The only issue is: it is not opened automatically. It is still available in the task bar. I have to open it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue multiple times. The best solution is close all the the applications and restart the machine. Then run the winappdriver.exe and execute the test scripts.